# Adding a div label to all blockquote elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The html:

```
 <blockquote>
test,test
</blockquote>

<p>test tow</p>
 <blockquote>
test2,test3
</blockquote>
```

I want to make the html to the folowing by jQuery:

```
      <div class="quote">
     <blockquote>
    test,test
    </blockquote>
   </div>

    <p>test tow</p>
  <div class="quote">
     <blockquote>
    test2,test3
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery` [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method

```
$("blockquote").wrap('<div class="quote" />');
```